# Using Python threads to make thousands of calls to a slow API with a rate limit

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, synchronization

I want to make thousands of calls to an API which is kind of slow -- tens of seconds to get a response. The only limit is that I can make at most one request per second. What's the best way to do this? I think the following code works, but I feel I should be able to make better use of the threading library somehow. I'm using python 3.3

```
last_job = datetime.now()
for work in work_list:
    while (datetime.now()-last_job).total_seconds() < 1 or threading.active_count() >= max_threads:
        time.sleep(.1)
    threading.Thread(target=work_function, args=[work]).start()
    last_job = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Did I get right that you can make a request per second, so while you wait 20 secs for 1st query result, you can instantiate another 19? Won't those additional 19 queries slow down response for the first one?

Comment: Why not use Celery to queue the jobs and set the rate limit?

Comment: @adam isn't it a bit overkill for this task?

Comment: @alko based on my experience of working with other people's API, I find it very beneficial to log whether there is a valid response or why the request failed, especially when something starts to go south. Celery can also keep track of these things.

Comment: @alko instantiating 19 more requests does not appear to slow down the first one.

Comment: @alko if the queue starts to build up and then several workers become free simultaneously, won't they all hit the API at the same time?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to run a bunch of jobs using a fixed-size thread pool, you can use [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for work in work_list:
        executor.submit(work_function, work)
```

If you want to ensure that you make at most one API call a second, then you need to do this from inside your `work_function`. You can't do it when submitting the job, because you don't know how long the job will queue up waiting for a thread to become available.

If it were me, I'd put the rate limiting code into its own class so that it's reusable:

```
from collections import Iterator
from threading import Lock
import time

class RateLimiter(Iterator):
    """Iterator that yields a value at most once every 'interval' seconds."""
    def __init__(self, interval):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.interval = interval
        self.next_yield = 0

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            t = time.monotonic()
            if t < self.next_yield:
                time.sleep(self.next_yield - t)
                t = time.monotonic()
            self.next_yield = t + self.interval

api_rate_limiter = RateLimiter(1)

def work_function(work):
    next(api_rate_limiter)
    call_api(...)
```

[`time.monotonic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) was introduced in Python 3.3; in older versions of Python you could use [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) but this can jump backwards when the system clock changes, so you would need to ensure that this doesn't cause overlong sleeps:

```
                time.sleep(min(self.next_yield - t, self.interval))
```

Comment: When I implement this solution, I get the error "TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class RateLimiter with abstract methods next"

Comment: @Greg: You are using Python 2.7, is that right? The method was called `next` in Python 2.

Comment: You can make it work on either version by using the code in Gareth's answer and just adding `next = __next__` inside the class immediately after you finish defining `__next__`; now it'll have the expected name on Py2 and Py3, without needing to change the code to run on each.